# Proper tracking of shopping cart events in Google Analytics / Enhanced E-commerce

Tags: google-analytics, e-commerce, enhanced-ecommerce

Currently, I'm integrating GA E-commerce events into an application and I would like to ask a recommendation.

In the application, I have 2 main entities: shopping cart and product lists (something similar to a wish list). I clearly understand that I should track e-commerce events when a user adds something to the shopping cart or removes something from it. What is not really obvious for me is: should I also track similar events when a user adds a product to one of his product lists?

From my understanding, these actions are very similar and I should also track e-commerce add/remove events when a user works with a product list. I would like to hear some pros and cons or best practices for analytics implementation in such a case.

Answer (score 0):

There is no such a thing as a 'proper' e-commerce tracking. Analytics would only report the data received from a client's side and report it in some standardized way.

That 'standardized way' implies that there are metrics for 'add to cart action' and 'checkout' actions. So firing 'add to cart' event on adding an item to wishlist would just be reported as 'add to cart'. Personally, I find it a little bit misleading since this skews the regular funnel data, inflating the real 'add to cart' numbers and you'll have no obvious opportunity to split them. And you'll get decreased Cart to Checkout ratio in your reports.
I'd recommend using plain events to track add/remove to wishlist actions.